# Objective-C path / color / alpha value animation programmatically

Tags: objective-c, animation

I am trying to implement background view like the animation in below link.
https://youtu.be/MA827rhcVRc

Is there any efficient way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[self.view setAlpha:1];
[self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The Video isn't working but maybe this will work for what you want?

Comment: Sorry, I just changed permission level of that youtube clip. Could you kindly check that link again?

Answer (score 0):

@interface ViewController : UIViewController { (press enter)
    IBOutlet UIView *view; (press enter)

Also you will have to put this in ViewController.h